# sample values by group with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have grouped data and I want to create a new variable `value` that will take the value 0 or 1.

1. Every group needs at least one observation where `value==1`.
2. But groups cannot have more than 2 observations where `value==1`.
3. Ideally I can set it so no more than 25% of groups only have one observation where `value==1`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

# sample can break the rules
tibble(group = c(rep("A", 3),
                 rep("B", 6),
                 rep("C", 4),
                 rep("D", 5))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(value = sample(c(0, 1), n(), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a listing of your unique group labels and shuffle those (here I get the unique group labels via `nest`). Then depending on whether the group is in the first 25% of rows of the data frame, you can assign either a) a random number between 1 and 2, or b) always 2. Finally, you can use the assigned number to define how 0s and 1s should be sampled for each group, and then unnest the result.

```
set.seed(0)
result <- df %>% 
  nest(data = -group) %>% 
  .[sample(1:nrow(.), nrow(.)), ] %>% # shuffle the group order
  mutate(
    value_count = ifelse(row_number() / n() <= 0.25, sample(1:2, n(), replace = T), 2)
  ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    count = nrow(data),
    value = list(sample(c(rep(1, value_count), rep(0, count - value_count)), count))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  select(-data, -value_count, -count)

   group value
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 B         0
 2 B         0
 3 B         0
 4 B         0
 5 B         1
 6 B         0
 7 A         1
 8 A         1
 9 A         0
10 D         1
11 D         0
12 D         1
13 D         0
14 D         0
15 C         1
16 C         0
17 C         0
18 C         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was beat to the punch, but here's another way to do it:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

# sample can break the rules
x <- tibble(group = c(rep("A", 3),
                 rep("B", 6),
                 rep("C", 4),
                 rep("D", 5)))

# Make all 'var' =1, then set all but first of each group to 0.
xx <- x %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(var = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(var = ifelse(var == 1, 1, 0))


pct_with_two <- .75 # percentage of groups with two 1's
samp_size <- floor(length(unique(xx$group)) * pct_with_two) #round down to whole number
addl_one <- sample(unique(xx$group), size = samp_size, replace = F)

xx %>% 
  mutate(var2 = case_when(
    group %in% addl_one & row_number() == 2 ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~0)) %>% 
  mutate(var = var+var2) %>% 
  select(-var2)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 2
#> # Groups:   group [4]
#>    group   var
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 A         1
#>  2 A         1
#>  3 A         0
#>  4 B         1
#>  5 B         0
#>  6 B         0
#>  7 B         0
#>  8 B         0
#>  9 B         0
#> 10 C         1
#> 11 C         1
#> 12 C         0
#> 13 C         0
#> 14 D         1
#> 15 D         1
#> 16 D         0
#> 17 D         0
#> 18 D         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>